# p:inputSwitch Listener only executes once

Tags: jsf, primefaces, frontend

I´m having a Problem with the Input Switch of Primefaces and the ajax change event for it. My Setup is following

```
<p:inputSwitch id="idOfTheSwitch"
               style="width: 40px"
               value="#{form.booleanWhichGetsChanged}">
    <p:ajax listener="#{form.methodWhichShouldGetCalled()}"/>
</p:inputSwitch>
```

The Problem here is the listener executes the Method in the Beans just once.

```
public void methodWhichShouldGetCalled() {
    // Should do something every time the Input Switch is getting switched.

    // Loads filtered Data
}
```

Versions:

```
    <!-- JSF -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.enterprise</groupId>
        <artifactId>cdi-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Primefaces -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces.extensions</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces-extensions</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.10</version>
    </dependency>
```

The Standard event for ajax ist `change`, isn´t it?
The Name of the Beans and the Method is changed for Stackoverflow.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Any errors in your browsers Javascript console?

Comment: and provide PF version  and JSF version and implementstion

Comment: better but not a real [mcve] yet. what if you add an explicit event?

Comment: Ok weird, just did an `maven clean install` and restarted my Tomcat which solved the Problem.